# How to easily build projects from a specific subdirectory in parallel with Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-project (Android) build with library *L*, app *A*, and examples *E1*, *E2*, *E3* (and possibly more). The directory layout is:

```
root (contains `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle`)
|
+- A (contains `build.gradle`)
|
+- L (contains `build.gradle`)
|
+- examples
   |
   +- E1 (contains `build.gradle`)
   |
   +- E2 (contains `build.gradle`)
   |
   +- E3 (contains `build.gradle`)
```

*A* depends on *L*, and each *E<n>* also depends on *L* (but not on *A*). The examples are stored in `examples/E<n>` subdirectories, and each example has its own `build.gradle` file. *A*, *L* and the example projects are included from the root's `settings.gradle` file (there is no `settings.gradle` file in `examples/`).

As all examples are independent of each other, I'd like to build them all in parallel without specifying each of them separately on the command line. Instead, I'd like to be able to simply write something like `./gradlew examples` from the root directory to do that.

I could create `task examples(dependsOn: E1:assembleDebug, E2:assembleDebug, E3:assembleDebug)`, but that does not scale well if new examples are added. I could probably also hook `tasks.whenAdded`and then modify the `examples` project's dependencies, but that does not seem to be very clean.

So, is there an elegant way to create a task that just builds other tasks from a certain subdirectory in parallel? It seems there's also a [group that a project can belong to](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:group), so a simple way to build all projects of a given group in parallel would also be fine.

Comment: Which exact task(s) do you want to depend on? You can't make a task depend on a project such as E1. If all tasks have the same name, you can just cd into `examples` and run them from there (using `gradlew taskName`).

Comment: Sorry, I was mixing up project and task dependencies. I've edited the question to clarify. The cd into `examples` trick does not work for me, I get `Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project 'examples'`. I guess I do need a second `settings.gradle` file for that?

Comment: You need to have `include "examples"` or `include "examples:E1"` in `settings.gradle` for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @peter-niederwieser's answer and comments I was able to achieve exactly what I wanted by adding this to the root's `build.gradle` file:

```
task examples {
    description 'Builds all examples.'

    dependsOn {
        subprojects.findAll {
            it.projectDir.parentFile.name == 'examples'
        }.assemble
    }
}
```

This solution does neither rely on example project naming nor on the project's group name (which does not equal the directory name if the project's `projectDir` is manually modified in `settings.gradle`).

Answer (score 1):

After adding `include "examples"` in `settings.gradle`, you'll be able to run `gradlew assembleDebug` from the `examples` directory. If you want more than that, you can additionally add the following to `examples/build.gradle`:

```
task examples {
    dependsOn { subprojects.assembleDebug }
}
```

Comment: Still does not work for me. After adding `include "examples"` to `settings.gradle` and running `../gradlew assembleDebug` from the `examples` directory I get `Task 'assembleDebug' not found in project ':examples'`.

Comment: You need to make E1,E2,E3 subprojects of `examples`, e.g. with `include "examples:E1"`.

Comment: Hmm, I do have included the individual examples in `settings.gradle` like `include ':E1'`, `project(':E1').projectDir = file('examples/E1')`. I'm doing this because I want to be able to build a single example from the root with just `./gradlew E1:assembleDebug` (no mention of `examples` here). But still I'd like to be able to build all examples with `./gradlew examples` from the root, too.

Comment: `include "examples:E1"` will solve all problems and not require to set `projectDir` explicitly, with the only difference that `gradlew :E1:assembleDebug` becomes `gradlew :examples:E1:assembleDebug`. If you don't like that, then declare an `examples` task in the root project as shown above.

Comment: Yeah, that's sort of an acceptable compromise. But even with your `examples` task I cannot build a *single* example anymore without specifying its full path name. But in exchange I can build all examples in a single blow. That seems to be the trade-off.

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. As long as you don't make any changes to `settings.gradle` and add the `examples` task to the root project, you can still build a single example in the exact same way as before.

Comment: Just adding your `examples` task to the root project does not work because `subprojects` would refer to *A* and 'L', too, which I do not want to build as part of the examples. And adding your `examples` task to a new `examples/build.gradle` file only works if I also modify `settings.gradle` to contain full paths in the `include` statements. Just adding `include ':examples'` does not work. While `./gradlew examples` does not complain, it simply does not build the examples, probably because Gradle does not recognize them as subprojects relative to `examples` as I modify `projectDir`.

Comment: Then use something like `dependsOn { subprojects.findAll { it.name.startsWith("E") } }`. Alternatively, use `include "ex:E1"` and set `projectDir` explicitly to `"examples/E1"` (all in `settings.gradle`), which will shorten the command to run a single example to `gradlew :ex:E1:assembleDebug`.